# Move Google Map marker in real time with watchposition function

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Place this inside the HTML head; don't use async defer for now -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        
        var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCWZjRe2CK8Hu2VN35AgZOQ7lQZKcI-UWM",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        }
        
        //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
        var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
        
        // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
        var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push());
      </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      var lat, lng;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 18

        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var pos = {lat: lat, lng: lng };
                _setGeoFire();
              var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var markerLabel = document.cookie;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]
    },
    map: map,
    label: markerLabel
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
    return function(e) {
      infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.User.g);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
  }(data)));
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
          
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Current Location');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }
      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
      function _setGeoFire(){
    geoFire.set("User", [lat, lng]).then(()=>{
            console.log("Location added");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2nPlSt_nM7PSKD8So8anbUbBYICFWcCA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need help updating my google map marker in real time. I'm using watchPosition to automatically keep updating in real time but then I want the map marker to also move as the user moves in real time. I don't want to have the user reload the page to see it move. I was using getcurrentlocation before but I learned that that doesn't update in real time so I changed it to watchPosition. Another user had the same problem a couple years ago. [Geolocation: moving only google maps marker without reload the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222330/geolocation-moving-only-google-maps-marker-without-reload-the-map?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
Seems like the code is outdated now though so it doesnt work for me Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I stop the Google Maps API from automatically refreshing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028795/how-do-i-stop-the-google-maps-api-from-automatically-refreshing)

Answer (score -3):

In initMap() try adding something like this:

```
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        moveMarker(map, marker);
      }, 3000);
```

and moveMarker() should look something like this:

```
function moveMarker(mapS, markerS){
    markerS.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( latx, longx ) );
    mapS.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( latx, longx ) );

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            moveMarker(mapS, markerS);
        }, 3000);
}
```

with latx, longx beeing your data aquired from watchPosition.

It's a bit flimsy, but it should work.

Comment: It says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function at like 86